# Inconsistencies in the rendering of lists

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, markdown-rendering

Can some of these inconsistencies be remedied?

http://meta.stackexchange.com behaves differently (somewhat *more* reasonable I'd say).
I posted a [**twin question on SE**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243011/169168). Note the *differences*.

== demo start ==

#### Bulleted list

- Item 1

  - There should be no extra vertical spacing between Item 1 and this line.
- Item 2 (but there should be here!)

Reset with `</p>`:

- Item 1

  - Just like here: no extra vertical spacing between this line and Item 1.

Reset with `</p>`:

- Item 1

  - But not here?
  - Sub-item 2

#### Numbered list

1. Item 1

   11. There should be no extra vertical spacing between this line and Item 1.
2. Item 2

Reset with `</p>`:

1. Item 1
   1.1 While this is not accepted as sub-item

Reset with `</p>`:

1. Item 1
   1.1 With the help of two blanks appended to above line
2. Item 2. Unlike http://meta.stackexchange.com, no vertical spacing before this item - like it should be

#### Mix

1. Item 1

   - Aligned top again?
2. Item 2

Comment: This is not just a rant, "because I found something". It keeps spoiling my attempts to format nicely and a constant nuisance. Since redesign of the site layout is underway, this would be a good opportunity to slip in a fix. Just ran into this again: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27144759/939860

Answer (score 6):

I guess we should all learn to type posts in HTML instead of counting on Markdown then:

```
<ol> <!-- Numbered List -->
  <li>First numbered point.
    <ul> <!-- Sub-Bullet List -->
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li>World</li>
      <p><li>And The Internet</li></p>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Next numbered point.</li>
  <li>Very next numbered point.</li>
  <p><li>Distant point.</li>
  <li>Groups with the last point.
    <ul> <!-- Sub-Bullet List -->
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li>World</li>
      <p><li>And The Internet</li></p>
    </ul>
  </li></p>
  <li>A numbered point outside the group.</li>
</ol>
```

1. First numbered point.

   - Hello
   - World
     And The Internet
2. Next numbered point.
3. Very next numbered point.
  Distant point.

  Groups with the last point.

  - Hello
  - World
    And The Internet
4. A numbered point outside the group.

Comment: Those paragraphs make me feel sick :( my eyes!

Comment: @misterManSam That and the way they're actually parsed into the DOM when wrapping an `<li>`... _*shudder*_

Comment: `<br />` dude, br...  and more realistically, just use separate lists with `start` attribute.

Comment: [congrats.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F276000%2Finconsistencies-in-the-rendering-of-lists)