# What is wrong with the vertical spacing in bulleted lists?

Tags: bug, design, markdown-rendering, formatting

There is a related question: [rendering of lists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276000/inconsistencies-in-the-rendering-of-lists). It is marked as "status-completed" however but I am not sure if it is the same problem.
Now I am on Windows+Firefox and I see such a picture:

[image]

Definitely the spacing is wrong. How does it happen?

---

Source (not mine - from [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315160/more-hierarchical-structure-needed-for-documentation-topics)):

```
<li><p>Who can modify the hierarchy?</p>

<ul>
<li>Anyone can add content to a requested topic.</li>
<li>Anyone of a certain rep can request a change to the hierarchy structure.</li>
<li>A relatively high number of high rep users are needed to approve the changes.</li>
</ul></li>
<li><p>What happens to Topics when the hierarchy is modified?</p>

<ul>
<li>The individual topics themselves can be stored as they are now or as
 Stack Overflow question pages are stored. However, they should be 
internally linked to the hierarchy and that hierarchy should be visible 
for browsing from the topic page.</li>
```

From the following markdown

```
- Who can modify the hierarchy?
 - Anyone can add content to a requested topic.
 - Anyone of a certain rep can request a change to the hierarchy structure.
 - A relatively high number of high rep users are needed to approve the changes.

- What happens to Topics when the hierarchy is modified?
 - The individual topics themselves can be stored as they are now or as Stack Overflow question pages are stored. However, they should be internally linked to the hierarchy and that hierarchy should be visible for browsing from the topic page.
```

Comment: I will take a closer look at this and fix it. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Fix for this should be live with next build on production.